# How to get the iframe origin in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I am listening on an iframe for when its contents change. When it does I would like to know what the current origin is of the content.

I can't access the content because it violates the same domain policy, but I am fine just knowing what content it is showing based on the url or host.

Any way I can have access to this from jQuery?

```
$('#snipletframe').load(function() {
  console.log("iframe content changed");

  // do something to figure out what content is showing
});
```

[EDIT]
I know the src property. The problem is that it refers to a resource which will potentially return a redirect. When this redirect happens I need to detect it. When I try to access the content the error is showing the iframe origin. This value holds the actual content host. So after the redirect I need to somehow get to this. The src property doesn't change with a redirect.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
var iframeURL = $('#iframeID').attr('src');
```

Comment: Sorry I could have been a bit more clear. I know the src property, because I make the iframe myself from js. I'll edit the question.